# Navigation Bar burger menu not appearing/working JAVA

Tags: java, android, xml

The hamburger menu does not appear on the toolbar. Swipe with no button as well not working. No error when compiling. A screenshot is attached as well as the xml and java code. Does the error comes from the fragment manager? previewing the xml file appears to be fine. How can i make it appear on all fragments as well.

Ps: new to android development

[image]

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context=".Navigation_Bar">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/purple_200"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_header_menu" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

java

```
public class Navigation_Bar extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public Navigation_Bar() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation__bar, container, false);
        Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer=(DrawerLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START));
        {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation__bar, container, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: At the end of `onCreateView()`, you need to return the `View` that you just set up there, not another newly inflated one; i.e., `return view;` instead.

Comment: this solve the problem